# How To: Make a Rotating Lazer Offset In Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to create an effect similar to the one found in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i0da_Pg5Jc

However, with verbatim code it does not function as demonstrated. I'm not sure if it's changes in unity or failure on my part but I'm using the same shader, and probably have watched this video like.. Oh Idk, 2501 times.. and I can't does it.

The best I can do is back and forth, Time.time does not work for me.

The code suggested..

```
Vector2 m_Offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time);
```

Doesn't do anything.

What I'm rolling with right now is..

```
void ProcessTextureShift()
{
    m_MaterialOffsetValue += m_OffsetShiftValue * Time.deltaTime;

    if (m_MaterialOffsetValue >= m_MaterialOffsetLimit)
        ResetMaterialOffset();

    m_WeaponBeam.material.
        mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(0, m_MaterialOffsetValue);
}
```

That produces an effect from start to finish but I was trying to accomplish the rotating/spinning of the rainbow in the video.

```
float m_MaterialOffsetLimit = 1.0f;
float m_MaterialOffsetValue = 0.0f;
float m_OffsetShiftValue = 2.0f;
```

Comment: You should post the salient parts of your code and explain what exactly is not working about it.

Comment: Thanks for the vocab lesson. :D I'll get the code up in a sec.

Comment: @code11 I updated the post, it produces an effect, it's just not the same. The one in the video just doesn't work.